# Django sitemap index pagination URL format

Tags: regex, django, sitemap

I have created a [sitemap index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index) for my Django site, since I have more than 50k URLs. Django says that it automatically paginates this for me, but I can't access the result in the URL.

Relevant code:

```
#urls.py
...
sitemaps = {
    'state': StateSitemap,
    'school': SchoolSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....    
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+).xml$','django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
)
```

The sitemap for "state" works just fine:

- www.example.com/sitemap-state.xml

However for school, which has 100k+ entries, and thus should be automatically paginated by Django, all of the following 404:

- www.example.com/sitemap-school.xml
- www.example.com/sitemap-school1.xml
- www.example.com/sitemap-school/1.xml

I know I'm misunderstanding how ".+" works as part of the sitemap index URL, but I'm stumped.

Which URL should I use to see the paginated sitemap result for "school" in my URL?

Comment: Looking at views code of django it seems pagination is handled by GET parameter named `p` and not `+` of regex. The `.+` part of regex is for section name and not pagination. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py

Comment: Yes, correct. Thank you for clarifying that and providing the link to the accurate documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `\` in your url.

```
url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+).xml$','django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

should be

```
url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$','django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```