# How to format index pagination url format django

Tags: python, django, xml

Question is really similar to [Django sitemap index pagination URL format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506818/django-sitemap-index-pagination-url-format)
but i didn't get the answer.
So, i need my url to be like this /sitemap-products-3.xml, where 3 is page by paginator. My current working links: sitemap-products.xml?p=3 . It's was generated by generic function (index). I did some work, and links look like sitemap-products-3.xml , but in urls.py, I don't know how to pass number of page in paginator, cuz the link gives me 404. Thats my sitemap.xml (index func)

```
def index(request, sitemaps, template_name='sitemap_index.xml', content_type='application/xml', sitemap_url_name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'):

    req_protocol = request.scheme
    req_site = get_current_site(request)
    sitemaps_lastmod = []
    sites = []  # all sections' sitemap URLs
    for section, site in sitemaps.items():
        # For each section label, add links of all pages of its sitemap

        if callable(site):
            site = site()
        protocol = req_protocol if site.protocol is None else site.protocol
        sitemap_url = reverse(sitemap_url_name, kwargs={'section': section})
        absolute_url = '%s://%s%s' % (protocol, req_site.domain, sitemap_url)
        sites.append(absolute_url)
        sitemaps_lastmod.append(sitemaps[section].index_lastmod(sitemaps[section]))
        # Add links to all pages of the sitemap.
        for page in range(2, site.paginator.num_pages + 1):
            absolute_url =  absolute_url.strip('.xml')
            sites.append('%s-%s.xml' % (absolute_url, page))

        if len(sites) > len(sitemaps_lastmod):
            for x in range(len(sites)-len(sitemaps_lastmod)):
                sitemaps_lastmod.append(sitemaps[section].index_lastmod(sitemaps[section]))
    sitez = zip(sites, sitemaps_lastmod)
    return render(request, template_name, {'sitemaps': sitez}, content_type=content_type)
```

and urls.py:

```
path('sitemap.xml', sitemaps.index, {'sitemaps': sitemaps_pages}),
path('sitemap-<section>.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps_pages}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to override generic sitemap func, in that function add to parameters page, delete this column

```
page = request.GET.get("p", 1)
```

then in urls.py place

```
 path('sitemap-<section>-<page>.xml', sitemaps.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps_pages}),
```

above your another sitemap urls